# Front shock Absorbers

Tags: fork, front, shocks

I bought a second-hand Chevrolet folding mountain bike with 26" wheels

I have had it a few days and the front shocks are making noise when they absorb.  The Previous Owner said its normal.

Today I opened the shock at a repairing shop.  There was no oil inside - it was dry.  What should I do?

And where is the position of a dumper in shocks?

Comment: Lack or research and not enough information to be able to help you.  If it has gone dry and you cannot order a rebuild kit then it is most likely toast.

Comment: We need more information regarding the shock. Brand, Model, age, and anything else you may be able to provide.

Comment: I have tweaked the grammar on your question, without significantly  changing the wording.  If I have changed it, please revert my changes.

Comment: Do you expect this fork to have an oil-filled damper, or that there was simply no lubrication oil inside the forks?   A clean and lube might be all it needs.  Any more than that probably means a replacement fork.

Answer (score 3):

What information is available on these models make it appears to be an lower cost Big Box Store quality bike. It has non descript components. These bikes typically have a very simple suspension. The shocks consist of a spring and plastic sleeves that act as bushings. The dampening rate can be adjusted by removing the plastic caps on the fork crown and inserting a long 5mm allen wrench. Tightening the screws preloads the springs and makes it stiffer. There is no rebound adjustment. Parts to rebuild these are usually not available. You can (with care) disassemble them to clean and lube the plastic sleeves. If this doesn't improve anything, a new fork will likely cost more than replacement cost of the whole bike. These types of bikes can be used as short term commuters, they won't last long if used for aggressive off road riding.